# "Ум на лестнице"

Tags: фразеология

Я слышала такое идеоматическое выражение "ум на лестнице" в значении "понимать что-то задним числом". То есть, когда сразу не смог найти достойного ответа, а придумал его тогда, когда уже поздно.
А сегодня мне попалась информация о том, что выражение это французского происхождения. А можно ли узнать подробнее об этом выражении?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

> А можно ли узнать подробнее об этом
> выражении?

См. http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ruwiki/1429125

Answer (score 1):

О происхождении есть напр. в Википедии, причём в русской статье есть примеры упоминания вариантов выражения в русских литературных текстах.

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Лестничный_ум

Везде ссылаются на рассказ Дидро о том, как на приёме его озадачили сильным аргументом - он не нашёл, что ответить. Уже покинув приём - спустившись к подножию лестницы (bas de l’escalier; это означало окончательно уйти - всё общение происходило этажом выше) он сообразил, что следовало сказать.

В переводах французское выражение l'esprit d'escalier, резюмирующее эту ситуацию, несёт неясный или изменённый смысл: русские варианты перевода (лестничный ум, остроумие на лестнице*) трудно понять без толкования (да и своё выражение об этом есть: "крепок задним умом"), в английском оно, как правило, употребляется без перевода, а немецкий буквальный аналог Treppenwitz употребляется по другим поводам.

- для перевода по смыслу я бы предложил "запоздалая находчивость"

Comment: в немецком Treppenwitz лестница и шутка по корням, лестница дрожит-трепещет, треппен, соответственно и коленки дрожат трепещут, вид(wits) потешный.
два русских корня в одном слове.